# How to fetch Particular records in DB2 and the immidiate following record

Tags: db2

I have the following data

EmpName....Emp_ID....Date..........Status

```
Adam............0001.........1 january.....Active

Adam............0001.........2 january.....Active

Adam............0001.........3 january.....Absent

Adam............0001.........4 january.....Active

Adam............0001.........5 january.....Active

Adam............0001.........6 january.....leave

Adam............0001.........7 january.....Active

Adam............0001.........8 january.....active

Adam............0001.........9 january.....absent

Adam............0001.........10 january....Active
```

I want the records where status is not active, and the immidiate following record where the status is active.. so my desired data should be

```
EmpName....Emp_ID....Date..........Status


Adam............0001.........3 january.....Absent

Adam............0001.........4 january.....Active

Adam............0001.........6 january.....leave

Adam............0001.........7 january.....Active

Adam............0001.........9 january.....absent

Adam............0001.........10 january....Active
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Note that relational table can have "next/previous" records only when some "order"-clause is provided, otherwise it makes no sense. DB2 supports LEAD/LAG OVER PARTITION/ORDER functions, so use'em. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-2-10-9

Comment: what platform and version of DB2?

Comment: I am using IBM Data Studio